# how to get label email from gmail with IMAP?

Tags: imap, gmail-api

i have a problem to get label email from Gmail. i was tried using Gmail API. that totally works fine. but that has a problem. gmail API does not have a listener (email idle). so now we using IMAP for getting the email. but i have no idea how to get id email by the label (update,promotions,social etc) with IMAP.

its possible to get id email by label using IMAP?
thanks

Comment: You think that labels are part of the mail server and not just part of the gmail web application?   check for folders might be close

Answer (score 0):

Labels are generally mapped to folder names, fairly directly.  Each message appears in any IMAP Folder that it is labelled with.

However, [GMail has a set of extensions to IMAP documented](https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap/imap-extensions) where you can fetch the labels for a message more directly.  They have added a `X-GM-LABELS` item for `FETCH` and `STORE`.

Here's there an example there:

```
a010 FETCH 1:4 (X-GM-LABELS)
* 1 FETCH (X-GM-LABELS (\Inbox \Sent Important "Muy Importante"))
* 2 FETCH (X-GM-LABELS (foo))
* 3 FETCH (X-GM-LABELS ())
* 4 FETCH (X-GM-LABELS (\Drafts))
a010 OK FETCH (Success)
```

Note special/system labels are prefixed with a \.

Comment: Foo is a placeholder for custom labels.  As far as I can tell the inbox categories are not labels, and are not available through IMAP.